# how to populate reference field when that document is updated

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have 2 collections Users and Bookings. I created userSchema and bookingSchema and routes of bookings and users.

User Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
    // select: false,
  },
});

userSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.find({ active: { $ne: false } });
  next();
});
```

Booking Schema

```
const bookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  from: String,
  to: String,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
});

bookingSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: 'user ',
  });

  next();
});
```

I defined my routes as follows

```
router.get('/api/bookings/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const booking = await Booking.findById(req.params.id);
  res.send(booking);
});
```

My issue is I created user document

```
 { 
  _id: "60ab239958c0ac2882d30531",
  active: true, 
  name: "rohit"
 }
```

and booking document

```
 {
    "_id": "60ab1fe50618d805581f154a",
    "from": "delhi",
    "to": "mumbai",
    "user": {
        "_id": "60ab1fac0618d805581f1549",
        "name": "rohit",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Now when I update active field to false in user "rohit" then when I fetch booking of rohit I get null in user field! (I can't delete pre middleware in user schema)

```
{
    "_id": "60ab1fe50618d805581f154a",
    "from": "delhi",
    "to": "mumbai",
    "user": null,
    "__v": 0
}
```